# Retrieve records of latest dates in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this table `price_date` in SQLite3.

```
id    info_id       price       date
"661"   "1"         "15.99"     "2018-10-15"
"1334"  "1"         "18.52"     "2018-10-01"
"439"   "2"         "24.48"     "2018-10-15"
"1113"  "2"         "25.97"     "2018-10-01"
"2"     "6"         "0.64"      "2018-10-15"
"678"   "6"         "0.66"      "2018-10-01"
```

I would like to retrieve the records with the latest date such that the output will look like this;

```
id    info_id       price       date
"661"   "1"         "15.99"     "2018-10-15"
"439"   "2"         "24.48"     "2018-10-15"
"2"     "6"         "0.64"      "2018-10-15"
```

Any hints on getting started in writing the sql code to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use correlated subquery

```
   select * from price_date t 
   where t.date = 
    ( select max(date) from price_date t1 
   where t1.info_id=t.info_id
     )
```

Answer (score 2):

use correlated subquery

```
select * from tablename t1 where date in
(select max(date) from tablename t2 where t1.info_id=t2.info_id)
```